# Autoclick only once every time the page is being loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing this piece of code and I want it to be executed only once every time the page is loaded.

So, I got my timeout function to hit the button when the page loads after some time (which is defined previously), **but I see it is autoclicking on the button as long as I stay on the page.**

```
setTimeout(function () {
$('#data-value button:number1').click();
}, 1000);
```

I want this specific button ("number1") autoclicked once 1 second after visiting that page. Of course, I want it repeat every other time i visit that page also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As long as you didn't retype the code and accidentally fixed it by replacing `setInterval` with `setTimeout`, I don't see why the above code would cause more than one click. Are you using a browser extension? Like Tampermonkey?

Comment: I marked this as "unclear what you're asking" because I can't see how the question makes sense unless the above code is in a loop somehow. The code does what you want it to do, so if we don't see the bigger picture, please add it to your question.

Comment: where are you calling setTimeout?

Comment: Indeed, it's making the loop somehow. Once it triggers click() after 1second, it doesnt stop, but continuing to do so until I close the page. And, yeah, I'm using Greasemonkey (similar to Tamper, but this is distribution for the Mozilla). Thanks for replies.

Comment: Based upon the question and comments, something is missing in the question that is relevant here. Please update your question with additional code around the function you have here, how is it in context to other code in your page?  Does your page do an auto refresh, it this in some dynamic code somewhere? etc.

Comment: The only way I see this happening is if the click triggers a reload of the page, and thus a re-run of the script. Which will schedule a new click, which will reload the page, etc. The only way to fix this is to write something to localStorage or use a cookie so the code doesn't re-run each time. This will permanently do it "once only" though, so closing and reopening the tab will not trigger a new click. The only way to fix *that* is to write a custom extension. (also: xy problem alert)

Comment: It's basically nothing. Only if(on_page('information')){ [code i provided above] }. I think so ChrisG. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be executed 1s after the page load, you want to combine Waleed's answer with your original solution

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    var button = $('#data-value button:number1');
    if (button) { button.click(); }
  }, 1000);
});
```

I've also added a check to see if the button exists, before calling the click() method.

**Explanation**

`$(document).ready(function() { } );` waits until the document has finished loading the DOM, then executes the anonymous function.

`setTimeout(function() { }, 1000);` sets a timeout of 1000 milliseconds then runs the anonymous function

`var button = $('#data-value button:number1');` gets the DOM button element

`if (button) { button.click(); }` checks to see if the button exists, then clicks it.

Comment: I cannot see how this would change what is posted nor how it addresses the repeated click issue - which we cannot even guess at as the OP question lacks the information to actually answer that (the real question here...)

Comment: Please explain what exactly is wrong in the original code and how your code fixes that, such that others can learn from your answer

Comment: I've updated my solution with an explanation. 
Mark if you read his question he is asking "I want this specific button ("number1") autoclicked once 1 second after visiting that page. Of course, I want it repeat every other time i visit that page also."

How is my solution not answering this question? The solution in the question fails to wait for document load.